# git does not work for some repo but work for others

Tags: git, github

I encountered a very weird issue for `git`.

I have three repo.s in github, say `repo1`, `repo2` and `repo3`.

On machine 1, I used to be able to clone and pull all three repos. 
However, suddenly I couldn't pull or clone `repo1` or `repo2`, but I can still pull `repo3` on machine 1.

The error message I receive is
git pull origin:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/MyGitAcount/scripts/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I did check the error message help for github. I double-checked that the network on machine1 has no problem.

Is there anyway I can fix this issue on machine1?

BTW, I can clone all three github repos on machine 2 without any problem. So I think there may be something wrong with the configuration on machine1?

[Answer]
I didn't change anything and the problem is solved after two days later when I tried it again.

I guess it is either because github has some issues at that time or because my network is not stable.

Comment: The 403 error indicates 'permission denied'. Compare the connection string being used on the two machines. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157583/git-credential-helper-cache-never-forgets-the-password to clear any cached credentials. Try changing http (if that is being used) to ssh or https.

Comment: Can you clone repo1 or 2 on machine 1 on a different place?

Comment: Also check out this site: https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors/